# Custom Login Using Firebase Add On Complete Listener to activity

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, firebase-authentication

Hi this is my  view model

```
class AuthViewModel(private val repository: UserRepository) : ViewModel() {
    /** Variables for custom login */
    var email: String? = null
    var password: String? = null
    var authListener : AuthListener? = null
    var authCompletedListener : OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>? = null
    /** Method to perform login operation with facebook */
    fun onClickLoginWithFacebook(){

    }
    /** Method to perform login operation with google */
    fun onClickLoginWithGoogle(){

    }
    /** Method to perform login operation with custom  */
    fun onClickCustomLogin(){
        repository.userLogin(email!!,password!!)
    }
    /** Method to perform sign up operation with custom */
    fun onClickSignUp(){

    }
}
```

when i click onClickCustomLogin i will call the userLogin fun from the repository instant

and this is my repository class

```
class UserRepository(private val appAuth: FirebaseAuth) {

    fun userLogin(email: String,password: String){
        appAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).
            addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener { })
    }
}
```

but according to MVVM the listener should be added in to the activity and it should be communicate with only view model so i want to implement the OnCompleteListener to my activity like this

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnCompleteListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
    }

    // onComplete Task here how it is possible

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimally, return the task from the repository.

```
fun userLogin(email: String,password: String): Task<AuthResult> {
    return appAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
}
```

Also, return it from the ViewModel method that calls through to the repository.  Then add listeners to it in the Activity.

This is just a minimal way to get started.  It doesn't handle configuration changes, nor does it fully abstract away the implementations details of Firestore from the Activity.  For all that, you will need a whole lot more code as an abstraction layer.

Comment: i cannot find the onComplete fun in the task